# Audio to text and again Audio using Google Cloud API by preserving timestamp, silence

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I Use Google Cloud API and Convert Audio to Text - Text must have timestamp.
I am able to achieve this using -

```
  'config': {
    'language_code': 'en-US',
    'enableWordTimeOffsets': true
  },
```

Now, convert Text to Audio. Send output of above step 1 to text to audio API. I want to send above generated text or JSON (from Audio to Text API) and convert my text to audio again. Audio should preserve timestamp so that I can get same original file with with breaks, pauses, silence with different voice. So, if my original file is of 1 minute duration, I want to generate same 1 minute duration file with different voice. So, it should preserve my pauses, silence

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve your pauses and silences by applying some logic I don't think this API provide this feature that can be used directly from enabling in config.

The Logic can be, as you are enabling the word time offsets you will be able to get start and end time of each word transcribed by the API, you can refer below link to find these timestamps.

[Getting Word TimeStamps](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-time-offsets)

Next thing you need to do is, store the End time of the first word in any variable, and compare it to start time of the next word. If they match then there is no pauses or silence, if they do not match you can find out the duration of silence by subtracting the the old end time to new start time. You need to change the end time value store in the variable with current end time after every iteration and can again compare with the new start time and so on...

**A algorithm can be made something like,**

```
firstiterationonly = 0;
oldendtime = null;
totalsilence = 0;
if(firstiterationonly = 0) //this will run  only once
{
    oldendtime = word.EndTime; // Initializing value of end time
    firstiterationonly = 1;
}
 else if(oldendtime != word.StartTime) 
 {
        silenceTime = word.StartTime - oldendtime;
        totalsilence = totalsilence + silenceTime;
       oldendtime = word.EndTime;
 }

else 
{
       oldendtime = word.EndTime; // when old end time and start time is equal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Speech to Text API doesn't have the feature to store the pauses and silences in the audio file.

As stated in the answer above, you would need to apply some logic to achieve the results.

Enabling the word time offset:
`enable_word_time_offsets = True`

gives the "start_time" and "end_time" of each word.

You need to use these timestamps to calculate the pauses between the words.

Once that is done you will need to build the string that you send to the text-to-speech API.

You should use the  [SSML format](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml) for the text to have exact pauses between words.